# Wait and Notify Deadlock situation in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

1. Thread t1 is going into Deadlock after `wait()` is hit. even though
   there is `notify()` in t2. Code is getting into deadlock.
   Not getting Print statement - "After wait is released ::::"
2. I can see both threads competing to acquire the monitor in `counterAdd()`. Therefore, I assumed notify will work.

   ```
   package com.java.thread.practice;

     public class WaitAndNotify4 {

           int counter = 0;

           /*
              CounterAdd() is to be accessed by both t1 and t2.
              If not synchronized not giving consistent output. 
           */ 
           synchronized int counterAdd(){
               return counter++;
           }

           public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

               // Creating method to call the threads.
               WaitAndNotify4 andNotify4 = new WaitAndNotify4();
               andNotify4.testRaceCondition();

           }

           private  void testRaceCondition() throws InterruptedException {

               // Thread t1 created and launched.

               Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                   @Override
                   public void run() {

                       for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                           synchronized(this){
                           if(i== 1){
                               System.out.println("Calling wait after count 1");
                               try {
                                // Assuming that this wait will be resumed by notify in t2.

                                   wait();
                                   System.out.println("After wait is released :::: ");
                               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                   e.printStackTrace();
                               }

                           }
                           }
                           counterAdd();
                       }
                   }
               });


               Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                   @Override
                   public void run() {
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                       for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                           if(i==2){

                               synchronized(this){
                                   System.out.println("Before releasing the counter :::::");
                                   notify();
                                   System.out.println("After releasing the counter :::::");
                               }

                           }
                           counterAdd();
                       }

                   }
               });



               t1.start();
               t2.start();

               t1.join();
               t2.join();

               System.out.println(" Sum value is found as ::::: "+counter);

           }
       }
   ```

Comment: Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 1):

You are synchronizing on different objects. In first case on object `t1`, in second on `t2`, in method `counterAdd` on `andNotify4`. In order to place lock on `andNotify4` all the time you need to do something like that.

```
public class Main {
    private int counter = 0;

    synchronized int counterAdd() {
        return counter++;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Main andNotify4 = new Main();
        andNotify4.testRaceCondition();
    }

    private void testRaceCondition() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    synchronized (Main.this) {
                        if (i == 1) {
                            System.out.println("Calling wait after count 1");
                            try {
                                Main.this.wait();
                                System.out.println("After wait is released :::: ");
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    counterAdd();
                }
            }
        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    if (i == 2) {
                        synchronized (Main.this) {
                            System.out.println("Before releasing the counter :::::");
                            Main.this.notify();
                            System.out.println("After releasing the counter :::::");
                        }
                    }
                    counterAdd();
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();

        System.out.println(" Sum value is found as ::::: " + counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solves the problem and clears the concept as well.

If you can throw some light on part as well.

"
I can see both threads competing to acquire the monitor in counterAdd(). Therefore, I assumed notify will work."

Comment: If they are two different threads with reference to different objects counterAdd() should print 10 always without synchronized keyword.